# remove characters from one string to another php

Tags: php

I have this string with special characters only

```
 $chars="¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬®¯°±²³´µ¶¸¹º»¼½¾ÀÂÃÄÅÆÈÊËÌÎÏÐÒÔÕÖ×ØÙÛÜÝÞßàâãäåæçèêëìî";
```

I have this another string with normal text with some of the special characters listed on the '$chars'occurrences.

```
   $string=" this is a normal text Â with some special ° characters I Þ  want to remove, not replace ê £";
```

How do I find the ocurrences and remove the chars listed on $chars and remove them from $string?

I was thinking using `str_replace()` with arrays but it is too much, I would need to make an array from $chars

Here there is the white list

`abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyzñáéíóúABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZÁÉÍÓÚ0123456789[]=+-¿?¡!<>$%^&*'"()/#@*,.:;_|`

Comment: Couldn't you just turn the logic upside down? Instead of black-listing, you should try to white-list the good chars. A simple regex for anything outside the white-listed chars would be trivial to do.

Comment: too late I have gathered thousands of them...Is there a way to make that work?

Comment: This one would be my white list. `abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyzñáéíóúABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZÁÉÍÓÚ0123456789[]=+-¿?¡!<>$%^&*'"()/#@*,./:;_|`

Comment: Sure, there is a way. Throw away those thousands and do it right! Black-listing is by it's very nature a limited beast, at best.

Comment: @aefxx How can I make work this white list?

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: wondering if you've tried:
preg_replace('/[^{insert white list here}]/', '', $string); ALSO, you could use preg_replace('/[^{same list all lower case}]/i', '', $string); where the "i" modifier allows it to ignore upper/lower case. (oh, and you'd have to quote the square brackets in the white list)

Comment: @UncaAlby could you give it a try please?, The white list is displayed above

Comment: Some of those characters wreak havoc with my PHP 5.6 interpreter. You may need to use their octal codes. I mean, jeez, I get division by zero errors!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the OP's comment:

```
$regex = '[^\w\s\[\]\=\+\-\¿\?\¡\!\<\>\$\%\^\&\*\'\"\(\)\/\#\@\*\,\.\/\:\;\_\|]';
mb_ereg_replace($regex, '', $string);
```

Comment: It retrieves ��������ª������

Comment: What was in `$string` that gave you this outcome?

Comment: `$string="//abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyzñáéíóúABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZÁÉÍÓÚ0123456789[]=+-¿?¡!<>$%^&*'()/#@*,.:;_| |||||||||| ] ¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬®¯°±²³´µ¶¸¹º»¼½ mmmmm onload onclick='' [ ? / < ~ # ` ! @ $ % ^ & * ( ) + = } | :  ; ' , > { space !#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~ <html>sdsd</html> ** *`` `` ´´ {} {}[] ````... ;;,,´'¡'!!!!¿?ña ñaña ÑA á é´´ è ´ 8i ó ú à à` à è`ì`ò ù &  > < ksks < wksdsd '' \" \' <script>alert('hi')</script>";
`

Comment: Updated the answer but keep in mind that `\w` in the regex might not suite your needs. You would need to replace it with the exact characters you wish to white-space if you need strict control.

Comment: there still appears ` ¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬®¯°±²³µ¶¸¹º»¼` on the retrieved string

Comment: Sry, my test say otherwise, please double check.